# Eliminar um user de um ficheiro.dat em C

Tags: c

Bom, eu preciso fazer um programa em qual eu crie uma base para arquivar dados de login de uma "empresa", ainda sou muito novo no conceito de c mas, não estou a conseguir fazer a parte que eu apago um user do ficheiro.dat sem apagar todos os outros

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>

typedef struct
{
    int codigo;
    char nome[200];
    char login[200];
    char password[200];
    char mail[200];
    char contacto[10];
}user;


void main()
{   
    FILE *fp;
    user utilizador;
    int cods=1;

    fp=fopen("Gest_User.dat","rb");
    system("color a");

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");

    char op;
    int dados,codigo_alt;

    do
    {
            printf("*********************************************\n");
            printf("* MENU                                      *\n");
            printf("*********************************************\n");
            printf("* Escolha a opção que deseja:               *\n");
            printf("*********************************************\n");
            printf("* 1: Inserir novo utilizador                *\n");
            printf("* 2: Alterar dados de um utilizador         *\n");
            printf("* 3: Consultar dados de um utilizador       *\n");
            printf("* 4: Listar dados de todos os utilizadores  *\n");
            printf("* 5: Eliminar um utilizador                 *\n");
            printf("* 0: Sair do Programa                       *\n");
            printf("*********************************************\n\n");
            printf("Digite uma opção: ");
            scanf("%d",&op);

        fclose(fp);

        switch(op)
        {
            case 1:             
                system("cls");

                utilizador.codigo=cods;

                fp=fopen("users.dat","ab");

                system("cls");

                if(fp==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Impossível abrir o ficheiro");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Código do user\n-> %d\n",utilizador.codigo);
                    printf("Digite o nome\n->");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",&utilizador.nome);
                    printf("Insira o nome de login\n->");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",&utilizador.login);
                    printf("Digite o mail\n->");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",&utilizador.mail);
                    printf("Digite a password\n->");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",&utilizador.password);
                    printf("Insira o número de contacto\n->");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s",&utilizador.contacto);   
                }
                fwrite(&utilizador,sizeof(utilizador),1,fp);

                cods++;

                fclose(fp);                 

                system("pause");
                system("cls");                      
                break;


            case 2:             
                system("cls");

                fp=fopen("users.dat","r+b");

                system("cls");

                if(fp==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Impossível abrir o ficheiro");
                }
                    else
                    {                   
                        if((fp=fopen("Gest_User.dat","r+b"))!=NULL) 
                        {                   
                            printf("Insira o código do utilizador\n->");
                            fflush(stdin);
                            scanf("%d",&codigo_alt);

                            if(codigo_alt==utilizador.codigo)   
                            {
                                printf("Código: %d\n",utilizador.codigo);
                                printf("Nome: %s\n",utilizador.nome);
                                printf("Login: %s\n",utilizador.login);
                                printf("Mail: %s\n",utilizador.mail);
                                printf("Password: %s\n",utilizador.password);
                                printf("Contacto: %s\n",utilizador.contacto);
                                printf("**************************************\n");
                                printf("Escreva todos os dados novamente para ser salvo!\n");
                                printf("Insira o código\n:");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%d",&utilizador.codigo);
                                printf("Digite o nome\n:");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%s",&utilizador.nome);
                                printf("Insira o nome de login\n:");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%s",&utilizador.login);
                                printf("Digite o mail\n:");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%s",&utilizador.mail);
                                printf("Digite a password\n:");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%s",&utilizador.password);
                                printf("Insira o número de contacto\n:");
                                fflush(stdin);
                                scanf("%s",&utilizador.contacto);
                            }
                            else printf("NAO EXISTE!!\n");      
                        }

                    }

                fclose(fp); 

                system("pause");
                system("cls");  
                break;  


            case 3:             
                system("cls");

                fp=fopen("users.dat","rb"); 

                printf("Insira o código do utilizador que quer consultar\n->");
                scanf("%d",&dados);

                do
                {
                    if(fread(&utilizador,sizeof(user),1,fp))
                    {
                        if(utilizador.codigo == dados)
                        {                       
                            printf("Código: %d\n",utilizador.codigo);
                            printf("Nome: %s\n",utilizador.nome);
                            printf("Login: %s\n",utilizador.login);
                            printf("Mail: %s\n",utilizador.mail);
                            printf("Password: %s\n",utilizador.password);
                            printf("Contacto: %s\n",utilizador.contacto);       
                        }
                    }
                }while(!feof(fp));  

                fclose(fp);

                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;


            case 4:             
                system("cls");

                fp=fopen("users.dat","rb");

                system("cls");

                if(fp==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Impossível abrir o ficheiro");
                }

                    do{
                        if(fread(&utilizador,sizeof(utilizador),1,fp))
                        {
                            printf("Código: %d\n",utilizador.codigo);
                            printf("Nome: %s\n",utilizador.nome);
                            printf("Login: %s\n",utilizador.login);
                            printf("Mail: %s\n",utilizador.mail);
                            printf("Password: %s\n",utilizador.password);
                            printf("Contacto: %s\n",utilizador.contacto);
                            printf("**********************************\n");
                        }
                    }while(!feof(fp));                  

                fclose(fp);                             


                system("pause");
                system("cls");  
                break;


            case 5:             
                /*fp=fopen("users.dat","w+b");

                fclose(fp); 

                system("pause");
                system("cls");*/
                break;  


            case 0: break;


            default: printf("Opção Inválida");  
        }
        system("cls");
        getchar();
    }while (op!=0); 
}
```

Comment: Comece por quando inserir um novo cliente, colocar a posição do cliente a ocupado. Para isso crie uma variável ocupado na estrutura. Depois para remover, faça um If( posição ocupado==1) , coloque ocupado a 0.
Quando libertarem a opção de resposta, eu irei colocar lá o código de como fazer

Comment: Você tem duas opções, ou ter uma flag em sua estrutura que indica se o usuário está ativo ou não e, neste caso, a eliminação recai no caso de alteração, ou eliminar fisicamente o registro e para isso você precisa copiar todos os demais registros para uma nova versão do arquivo e depois eliminar o arquivo antigo e renomear a nova versão que não terá mais tal usuário.

Comment: Visto que não dá para colocar aqui uma resposta, envio o código pelo codeshare. Usei uma função para a remoção de clientes. Usar funções torna o código mais fácil de perceber do que se estiver tudo no main. https://codeshare.io/programa

Comment: Eu testei  a linha de cod enviada mas ele apenas pergunta o codigo e depois fecha o programa, deveria fazer algo nele antes de abrir? ou ja estava por completo o que foi enviado?